# Solving a word problem using a Venn diagram

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **problem**: In a group of $265$ persons, $200$ like singing, $110$ like dancing and $55$ like painting.
>
> If $60$ persons like both singing and dancing, $30$ like both singing and painting and $10$ like all the activities, then how many like only dancing and painting?

**Solution**:

[image: Venn diagram]

Also $x+y =50$ and $y+z=25$.

I want to find $y+10$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three unknowns ($x, y, z$) and knowing the total number of people gives you the third equation that you need to solve the system. In other words, you have:

$$
\begin{align}
y+x=50\\
y+z=25\\
y+x+z=65
\end{align}
$$

which hopefully should not be a problem to solve.

Comment: This means y=10 And answer is 20

Comment: @rst: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: But in book answer is given 10.

Comment: @rst: Then perhaps "both singing and dancing" should be interpreted as "both singing and dancing [and not painting]" etc. That way you'd have $S\cap D-S\cap D\cap P=60$ instead of 50 and $S\cap P-S\cap D\cap P=30$ instead of 10. Then $y$ would still be 10 (your answer), but "both dancing and painting" is interpreted as "both dancing and painting but not singing". It's not always perfectly clear what is meant, I don't think.

Comment: question is "people who like only dancing and painting".Thanks a lot.I didn't pay attention on the last line